# How to do HTTP Basic Authentication in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am totally new to ionic. In my project, the API both have a basic authentication. The API then run OK on Postman, but don't know how to do it on ionic. I have research for several articles but they need a lot of step to follow after some steps I get lost.

Here is my code:

```
app.controller('MainViewController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method:"GET",
    url:"my_url"
  }).then(function(categories){
    console.log(categories);
  });
});
```

I got the error on console:

> GET "my_url" 401 (Unauthorized)

Here is the setup on Postman:
[image: Postman setup authorization]

And the header then:
[image]
Do you know what is the proper way to do this on ionic

Answer (score 2):

You can set authorization header in app config as follow

```
app.run(['$http', function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Your key';
}]);
```

You can also do as follow

```
$http({
    url : "URL",
    method : 'GET',
    header : {
        Content-Type : 'application/json',    
        Authorization: 'key'
    }
 }).success(function(data){
    alert(data);
 }).error(function(error){
    alert(error);
 })
```

Comment: but how can I set basic authen every time request an api this? what if the key change automatically? @divyesh-savaliya

Comment: then obviously you have to change key..and key not change automatically...it has some logic on server side

Comment: This is the default code of ionic, how can I put that code in to this function?
`app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
`

Answer (score 0):

// Define the string

```
var string = 'Hello World!';
```

// Encode the String

```
var encodedString = btoa(string);
console.log(encodedString); // Outputs: "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
```

// Decode the String

```
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString); // Outputs: "Hello World!"
```